# QT Test Main Multiple Definition, but using that macro for application creation

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, scons, qttest

I am trying to create a new test class for each of my classes in QT. I have this working with a single file, but that relies on QTEST_MAIN creating an application for me and calling it in more than 1 file creates a multiple definition error.

I have tried creating a main() on my own and then running a qExec, but I have been unsuccessful. I am using SCONS to build and haven't found any resources on making that work within that build system.

Here is my latest failed attempt:

```
#include <QtTest/QtTest>
#include "path/test1.h"
#include "path/test2.h"

class TestMain : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
private:
    TEST1 test1;
    TEST2 test2;

private Q_SLOTS:
    void initTestCase();

};

void TestMain::initTestCase(){
    //these are causing multiple def of main
    test1.initTestCase();//these only have data to setup the UI to test on
    test2.initTestCase();//these only have data to setup the UI to test on
}

QTEST_MAIN(TestMain);
```

Is there a clean way to achieve something like this without using the QTEST_MAIN macro, or using it to call a single slot that then collects all the tests from the separate classes?

All the other solutions I've found make a new main and I would rather not do that due to the fact that it creates more setup issues such as creating a QApplication that would have to accept parts from all the classes and duplicated code.

Comment: Why tag scons for this question?

Comment: that is what I am building with

Comment: do you think the problem or the solution is with scons? if not, then tagging scons is an error.